# SQL Update - Not updating multiple rows in a for loop

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sqlite, datagridview

I have a DataGridView(DGV) linked to a SQlite database. I want to update some info on the DGV. So, I have a context menu that lets me change one column and update the DB as well. I want to have the ability to select multiple rows and edit as well. For ex: if i select five rows and change the type from alarms to errors ; the change is reflected in the DGV and then when i look into the database , the change isnt reflected. Only one row is updated.

My code snippet is below

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            SQLiteTransaction SQLiteTrans = connection.BeginTransaction();
            SQLiteCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            MessageBox.Show(r.ToString());
            if (r.Cells["typeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString().Contains("#") == false)
            {
                r.Cells["typeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value = r.Cells["typeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString() + " # " + max;
            }
            else
            {
                r.Cells["typeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value = r.Cells["typeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString().Substring(0, r.Cells["typeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString().IndexOf("#")) + "# " + max;
            }
            string querytext = "Update LogDatabase set Type = \"" + r.Cells["typeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value + "\" where HashKey = \"" + r.Cells["hashKeyDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString() + "\"";
            cmd.CommandText = querytext;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SQLiteTrans.Commit();    
        }
```

I dont have too much experience with SQL. So, im not sure if something is wrong with how ive updated the database!

What do i have to edit to make sure all the rows are updated in the DB as well?!

Help appreciated.

***Edit: Tried checking the query before its sent.***

When i try editing multiple rows in the DGV without sorting the DGV under any column it works and updates all the rows simultaneously... But When I try to sort them based on "Type" and then edit the rows, the same query is passed ! :| (Hash Key doesnt change)

Its like, the one row keeps moving up the list of rows and is always the ***row r***  in the for loop.

***Edit 2: Its definitely a problem with the rows of the DGV***
Everytime I sort the DGV and then try to edit the fields, the queries have hashkey values different from the once that i selected. Its like the row ids are changed completely after one update. It looks like the DGV automatically sorts once one row is updated !

Is there a way to disable this???!

Comment: What is your question?  Does this code compile?

Comment: @Abe: The `for` loop indicates that he wants multiple items to be updated, but he says only one row is being updated when he runs this.

Comment: @techmanc: Try stepping through the debugger and copying out the querytext you're getting in each iteration of the `for` loop. Then try running those commands one at a time directly against the DB. What happens?

Comment: @techmanc also note that the recommended way of passing parameters to an SQL query is using the SQLiteParameter (look at SQLiteCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue) object, rather than manually inserting them into the query as this potentially enables SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: This is really weird. 1. When i try editing multiple rows in the DGV without sorting the DGV under any column it works and updates all the rows simultaneously... But When I try to sort them based on "Type" and then edit the rows, the same query is passed ! :| (Hash Key doesnt change)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you weren't increasing max counter.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
using (SQLiteTransaction SQLiteTrans = connection.BeginTransaction())
{
    SQLiteCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
    MessageBox.Show(row.ToString());

    var txtValue = row.Cells["typeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value;
    if (txtValue.Contains("#"))
    {
        txtValue = String.Format("{0} # {1}", txtValue, max);
    }else
    {
        txtValue = txtValue.SubString(0, txtValue.IndexOf("#")) + "# " + max.ToString();
    }
    string querytext = "Update LogDatabase set Type = @type where HashKey = @key";
            //Create your SqlParameters here!
    cmd.CommandText = querytext;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SQLiteTrans.Commit();    
    max++; //You weren't increasing your counter!!
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using double quotes in your SQL query to delimit your string values. Replace them for single quotes:

```
string querytext = "Update LogDatabase set Type = '" + 
                    r.Cells["typeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value + 
                    "' where HashKey = '" +  
                    r.Cells["hashKeyDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString() + 
                    "'";
```

Also, beware of [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Your code is not dealing with that.

Comment: Is there any problem in using double quotes? It doesnt seem to affect the query that is sent! and I thought SQL injection isnt a problem here because , I send the HashKey and Type... (no possibility of escape characters)

Comment: Well, in SQL Server double quotes are used for object specification as opposed to single quotes, which are used for string delimiting. I don't really remember if that's the case for SQLite, but i would give it a shot. As for SQL Injection, you have to be sure none of the data involved have the possibility to be entered by the user. But you'd be safer by using parameters.